# Transform encoded UTF-8 characters to special accented characters in android

Tags: java, android, utf-8, non-ascii-characters, utf8-decode

In Java, I have a string obtained from an API, which looks like:

> Hola, &#233;sto es una frase con acentos.

And I want to have:

> Hola, ésto es una frase con acentos.

Not only for this example, I need it for all UTF-8 encoded characters.

I've been looking for this for an hour but I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't encoding, it's an HTML numeric character reference.

The easiest way to deal with it is add the Apache Commons Lang library to your project, and call [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your text is encoded with SGML entities, a possible approach is to use a XML parser to decode it (though it might be not so smart):

```
public static String decodeSgml(String src)
    throws org.xml.sax.SAXException,
    javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException,
    java.io.IOException
{
    InputSource inputSource=new InputSource(new StringReader("<x>"+src+"</x>"));
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory factory=javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder docBuilder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc=docBuilder.parse(inputSource);
    return doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
}
```

(If the number of exceptions thrown by the method looks excessive, you could maybe re-throw some of them as ServiceConfigurationErrors, or store some of the variables as static members).